# JPanel key listener not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I am making a large program with multiple classes and am having issues with some code that I wrote. My Mouse listener works just fine and using the same steps, my key listener does not. My code is as follows;

**main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    window._init_(panel);
}
```

**Window init method:**

```
public void _init_(JPanel panel){
    window = new JFrame("Asteroid");
    window.setPreferredSize(size);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(closeOpp);
    window.add(panel);
    window.getContentPane();
    window.setResizable(resizable);
    window.setFocusable(focusable);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(location);
    window.setVisible(visibility);
}
```

**Panel init method:**

```
public MainPanel(){
    //panel initialization
    System.out.println("inside constructor");
    panel = new JPanel();
    this.add(panel);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.setSize(Window.size);
    this.setFocusable(Window.focusable);
    this.add(b);
    this.setVisible(Window.visibility);
}
```

**Panel listener methods**

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("key pressed");
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("key released");
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("mouse clicked");
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
```

ps. The panel implements all of the used listeners, all variables are defined, and the program runs with no errors

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of why we don't recommend `KeyListener`.  You should have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for a solution which solves the short commings of `KeyListener`

Comment: I'm looking at `b` and I'm wondering if it's a `JButton`, which is likely stealing focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting you focus to your frame rather than the JPanel, But even changing the focus to the JPanel will provide a level of unpredictable behavior because it is really easy to lose focus of the JPanel. I suggest you use Key Binding or Change your keylistner method and other override methods to attach to the JFrame rather than the JPanel to assure focus is kept during use of application.

Comment: *"Your setting you focus to your frame rather than the JPanel"* - I don't see anywhere they call `requestFocusXxx`